# Sine wave which x axis follows a function f(x)

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, parametric

The traditional sine wave $\sin(x)$ is the sine wave that is wrapped around the function $f(x) = 0$. *I.e.*, the $x$ axis. Is it possible to make an algorithm/formula/whatever so that you can take any function, e.g. $f(x) = x^2$ or $f(x) = tan(x)sec(x)$, and then produce a function that's either parametric or cartesian that represents the original $f(x)$ but with the sine wave along it.

For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786921/sine-curve-circular-transform-parametric-equations) is a case where the sine wave is along a circle, and it's given in parametric form. But if for example it was along a parabola, or a line, a hyperbola, or an ellipse, or even just another $\sin(x)$, is there a general way to kind of "bend" the sine wave so that it would follow that curve?

Examples: $1/x$ would look like this: https://prnt.sc/jsji21

$x^2$ would look like this: https://prnt.sc/jsjg7o

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. But if I get it, just add your function to sin($x$). e.g. $f(x) = x^2 + \sin(x)$ is like having $x^2$ on an 'axis' shaped like sin($x$).

Comment: @DanSp. This doesn't necessarily work, it only works for $x^2$, and not entirely as intended. This is what I want: http://prntscr.com/jsjg7o , and this is what I get if I use your method: http://prntscr.com/jsjfg9. I don't see what's not very clear about it, it's just the basic sine wave but it's glued onto another curve/function. With $f(x) = 1/x$ it would look like this: http://prntscr.com/jsji21 and so on.

Comment: Ah, I understand. $f(x)$ is a perpendicular distance from the 'axis'. Are you hoping to just plot data points (this would be doable). Finding a resultant function will not work because as you can see in your $1/x$ function, does not map x onto y. Example: at $x=5$ there will be multiple y values.

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean. It's probably not possible then.

Comment: On second thoughts, I don't think that makes it unfeasible: as for the case of the sine curve around a circle: http://prntscr.com/jsk3h1 this is $r\ =\ 10\ +\ \sin80\theta$, and at x = 10 you can see there are multiple y values, but the function can still be defined parametrically. I have modified my question to allow for parametric solutions also.